# Using maven properties in command line

Tags: maven

Can we use maven properties such as `${maven.project.version}` and `${maven.build.timestamp}` in command line?
For example: `mvn clean package -Dbuild.number=${maven.project.version}-${maven.build.timestamp}`. I know it is possible to set it as property in pom file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't..

But you can override the properties in your pom.xml with command line parameters by the same name

Comment: yes, but how?..